# Unable to remove the space from column names in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I have parquet dataset column names with spaces in between the words like for eg: `BRANCH NAME`. Now, when I replace the space with `"_"` and try printing the column it results in an error. Below is my code with multiple approaches followed by error:

**Approach 1:**

```
Var df= spark.read.parquet("s3://tvsc-lumiq-edl/raw-v2/LMSDB/DESUSR/TBL_DES_SLA_MIS1")


for (c <- df.columns){
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace(" ", ""))
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
df = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((curr, n) => curr.withColumnRenamed(n, n.replaceAll("\\s", "")))
```

**Approach 3:**

```
val new_cols =  df.columns.map(x => x.replaceAll(" ", "")) 

val df2 = df.toDF(new_cols : _*)
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "BRANCH NAME" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
```

Below is the schema:

```
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- dms_timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BRANCH NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BRANCH CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEALER NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEALER CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEALER CATEGORY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRODUCT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATION DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHANNEL TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DELAY DAYS: string (nullable = true)
```

I have had also referred multiple SO posts but didn't help.

Comment: can you add sample data ?

Comment: I can't print the data since when I try to print, it gives the same error

Comment: Your approach 3 should be definitely working, may be check if there are any other special characters, can you check with df.show(false) before changing column names?

Comment: It results into an error

Comment: What error do you get with `df.show(false)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Andrey 's update:

Now we can correctly load parquet files with column names containing these special characters. Just make sure you're using spark after version 3.3.0.

---

If all the datasets are in parquet files, I'm afraid we're out of luck and you have to load them in Pandas and then do the renaming.

Spark won't read parquet files with column names containing characters among " `,;{}()\n\t=`" at all. AFAIK, Spark devs refused to resolve this issue. The root cause of it lies in your parquet files themselves. At least according to the dev, parquet files should not have these "invalid characters" in their column names in the first place.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27442 . It was marked as "won't fix".

Comment: Checked your link - it was marked as resolved and the PR fixing it was merged into master (they claim it is part of version 3.3.0): https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/35229

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed in [Spark 3.3.0 release](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27442) (I tested). So your only option is to upgrade (or use pandas to rename the fields).

Comment: Thank god! But I think it should have been added long back.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
df
.select(df.columns.map(c => col(s"`${c}`").as(c.replace(" ",""))):_*)
.show(false)
```

Comment: Same error. Is it something with the parquet ?

Comment: oh.. I think you should be some special characters between column name.

Comment: There are no special characters. I have displayed the schema

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
val dfnew =df.select(df.columns.map(i => col(i).as(i.replaceAll(" ", ""))): _*)
```

Comment: Is it on the parquet dataset? Or some else ? Because my code is working for non parquet files

Comment: Its non parquet dataset, Can you try dropping column BRANCH NAME from dataframe and the apply the above logic? to see if there any issue with that particular column.

Comment: Yeah I tried creating new column with that column's data but while displaying, it gives the same error